# How to get sftp to respect my umask setting

Tags: sftp, umask

I'm trying to get sftp to give me a umask of 002 but it keeps behaving like the umask is 022. How do I get it to do that?

Red Hat 7.4

/etc/ssh/sshd_config has the line:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -u 002
```

I've also tried

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -u 0002
```

After each change I make to sshd_config I issue the following command:

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd.service
```

Then in a separate window I log into sftp.

Once I've uploaded the file in sftp, then "ls -Fla" in the shell session returns:

```
drwxrwsr-x. 2 [myID]  [myGroup]         32 Dec 28 17:37 ./
drwxrwxr-x. 4 [siteID] [siteGroup]      50 Dec 26 18:44 ../
-rw-r--r--. 1 [myID]  [myGroup]    9173334 Dec 28 17:37 [myUploadedFile]
```

(last line having r-- as the group permission)

where I would expect:

```
drwxrwsr-x. 2 [myID]  [myGroup]         32 Dec 28 17:37 ./
drwxrwxr-x. 4 [siteID] [siteGroup]      50 Dec 26 18:44 ../
-rw-rw-r--. 1 [myID]  [myGroup]    9173334 Dec 28 17:37 [myUploadedFile]
```

(last line having rw- as the group permission)

I've also tried

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -u ug=rwx
```

but that one causes sftp to close the connection.
At least it confirms that I'm updating the right configuration file.

Comment: Are you sure the remote umask is the problem? Your SFTP client may be setting explicit permissions on the remote file.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that `umask` values only *reduce* permissions, never adds them.

So if your local file was permission 0644 (-rw-r--r--) then the umask will not add a group write flag.  The umask will remove "other write"; so if your local file was 0666 then the remote would be 0664.

If you want to ensure the remote file has group write then you might want the `-m 664` flag instead.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. Additionally, I now found the same options the `sftp-server` manpage describe apply to `internal-sftp` - all the while I tried to find documentation specific to the latter.

Answer (score 0):

In your sshd config file, try setting "ForceCommand" on your groups

```
Match Group {GROUP_NAME}
   ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 0002
```

Restart your sshd process for the new settings to take effect

Comment: Do you have some reason to believe the normal subsystem configuration isn't working here?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your sftp usage pattern, it might be a viable approach to change the behaviour from the client side.

If you are able to modify the permissions of the file you are 'putting' (or they are already desirable), you can use the -p parameter with `put`, which will copy permissions and file modify time (works with `scp` as well).  Assuming your local file has the permissions you desire, the below should work:

```
put -p <filename>
```

Alternately, if you are receiving files, `lumask` is provided to set local permissions.